# AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records - Credentials fail for java SDK but not CLI

Tags: java, scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sdk

When using the Java s3 sdk `aws-java-sdk-s3:1.11.542` in Scala, I'm getting a "AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records."

I've verified that I can access the bucket and run commands, e.g: `aws s3 mv s3://{bucket} ./ --recursive` and `aws s3 ls s3://{bucket}`.

My implementation for the client is:

```scala
implicit val s3Client: AmazonS3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
      .standard
      .withRegion(new DefaultAwsRegionProviderChain().getRegion)
      .withCredentials(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain)
      .build
```

I've tried explicitly using `BasicAWSCredentials`, `EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider`, and `ProfileCredentialsProvider` too.

Edit: Was an issue with my default profile and okta that I'm using

Answer (score 0):

you can use [AWSCredentialsProvider](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentialsProvider.html)    API

```
implicit val awsCredentialsProvider = new AWSCredentialsProvider {    
          override def getCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(AWSKey, AWSSecret)
          override def refresh(): Unit = ??? 
    }
```

and use the `awsCredentialsProvider` to create a `AmazonS3ClientBuilder.`

```
implicit val s3Client: AmazonS3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
      .standard
      .withCredentials(awsCredentialsProvider)
      .withRegion(new DefaultAwsRegionProviderChain().getRegion)
      .build
```

Comment: Same problem, my guess is I might have a conflict with a library. Debugging through the SDK's http request.